# .nwv .nwf file in Android system

Tags: android

There are some .nwv /.nwf files in Android system .

Example:

```
../config/en.us/audio/v139/v139_189.nwv        
../config/en.us/audio/m252/m252a12e.nwv        
../config/en.us/audio/m252/m252a22e.nwv        
../config/en.us/audio/m252/m252a10e.nwv       
../config/en.us/audio/m252/m252a3fe.nwv        
../config/en.us/audio/m252/m252a11e.nwv        
../config/en.us/audio/m252/m252a21e.nwv        
../config/en.us/audio/m252/m252a24e.nwv        
../config/en.us/wave/dallas/0000/S072.nwf      
../config/en.us/wave/dallas/0000/S074.nwf      
../config/en.us/wave/dallas/0000/S075.nwf      
../config/en.us/wave/dallas/0000/S076.nwf      
../config/en.us/wave/dallas/0000/S077.nwf      
../config/en.us/wave/dallas/0000/S079.nwf      
../config/en.us/wave/dallas/0000/S080.nwf      
../config/en.us/wave/dallas/0000/S083.nwf
```

Are they audio files? Who will play them?  SoundPool or MediaPlayer ? any other?

Thank you for your help ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick [Google search](http://www.google.com/search?q=nwv%20file%20extension) will answer those questions for you.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But  who will play these audio files in Android ?